# Angular pass arguments from controller to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angular and I work with legacy code.
In controller I got:

```
$scope.data= GenerateService.generate(DataService.all, {
            showOptions : true,
            sort : {
                name: "created",
                dir: "DESC"
            }
        });
```

this with another directive somehow generates data on site.
And I also got DataService witch invokes web service:

```
angular.module('services-data-service', []).factory('DataService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('rest/data/:method/', {}, {
        all:{method:'GET',  params:{method:'all', param:1},           isArray:true}
    });
});
```

I can't modify GenerateService, but I could modify  DataService, could anybody tell me how dynamicly pass arguments from controller to DataService request?

Now service generates request like:

```
http://localhost:8087/my-app/rest/data/all?isArray=false&param=1&data=0&fetch=10
```

So GenerateService somehow add `&data=0&fetch=10` parameters. I added manually param=1, **so please tell me how pass arguments from controller to DataService**

Comment: Have you read the docs on ngResource?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource